# Combining a pdfview and another widget on the same page

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm working on a flutter application that will display terms and condition in pdf and accept check box on the same page. I'm trying to display the pdf document on top and the check box at the tail end of the pdf page.

I have tried to use Expanded and ListView widget to hold both the pdfview and the checkbox widget but I got error.

Here is what I have tried:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_pdfview/flutter_pdfview.dart';

class TnC extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _TnC createState() => _TnC();
}

class _TnC extends State<TnC>{

 bool isChecked = false;

Widget iAccept() {
    return Container(
      //alignment: Alignment.topRight,

      child: Column(children: <Widget>[
        CheckboxListTile(
          onChanged: (val){
            val = val==true? true : false;
            setState(() {
              if(val == true){
               isChecked = false;
              }else{
                isChecked = true;
              }
            });
            isChecked = val;
            val ? wiget.rememberMe.text =  '1': wiget.rememberMe.text = '0';
          },
          title: Text(
            'I Accept',
            style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.cyan,
                fontSize: 18.0,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
          ),
          value: isChecked,
          controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.leading,
        )
      ]),
    );
  }
  
  String? _localFile;

  @override
  void initState(){
    super.initState();
    Httpcl.loadPDF().then((value){
      setState(() {
        _localFile = value;
      });
      
    });
  }
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
     
     return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: h1(txt: 'Terms & Condition'),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),

      body: _localFile != null? Expanded(child: ListView(
        children: [
          Container(
            child: PDFView(
              filePath: _localFile,
              autoSpacing: false,
            ),
          ) ,
           iAccept()
        ] 
        )) : Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),

     );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this as body,
body: _localFile != null?  Column(
children: [
Expanded(
child: PDFView(
filePath: _localFile,
autoSpacing: false,
),
) ,
iAccept()
]) : Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),

and use this,

Widget iAccept() {
return Padding(
padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
child:
CheckboxListTile(
onChanged: (val){
val = val==true? true : false;
setState(() {
if(val == true){
isChecked = false;
}else{
isChecked = true;
}
});
isChecked = val;
val ? wiget.rememberMe.text =  '1': wiget.rememberMe.text = '0';
},
title: Text(
'I Accept',
style: TextStyle(
color: Colors.cyan,
fontSize: 18.0,
fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
),
value: isChecked,
controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.leading,
)
);
}